# Looking for spam mails

Tags: spam-prevention, email-filter

I am looking for a bundle of spam mails to use with my experiments with Bayesian spam filtering.

Is there any resource for this or does anyone have a bundle to share with me?
Something around 4-6gb zip:ed would be a nice start.

Feel free to filter out your own email-address, though this is for personal use and it won't be shared with anyone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start a Blogger blog, put up a few posts with an extra Gmail address in the text. Begin to get spam. Harvest with POP3 or IMAP. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure everyone has a bundle of these emails. But privacy would be breached for most companies if their network administrator share this with you. I don't get much spam if any in my personal email, good luck. :-/

Do it yourself SPAM:

"[How to get spam.](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=15260)"